# MS Access: Join on three tables with condition

Tags: ms-access, join

In an MS Access database I try to make a join on three tables with conditions.

My current approach does not work:

```
SELECT    
P.[COL1],    
P.[COL2],    
P.[COL3],    
P.[COL4],    
P.[COL5],    
P.[PRGUID],    
P.[COL6],    
P.[COL7],    
ARTIKEL.[COL1],    
ARTIKEL.[NUMBER],    
P.[PST_NR],    
RECHNUNGEN.[RG_STORNO]    
FROM P, A, R
                        WHERE R.[TIMEST] > #{from:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}#    
                        AND R.[TIMEST] < #{until:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}#     
AND A.[NUMBER] = VAL(P.[PLUX])    
AND R.[RGUID] = P.[PRGUID] "
                        ;
```

because the datasets in table P that do not have a corresponding entry in table A (condition: A.[NUMMER] = VAL(P.[PLUX])) are not returned.

I tried an approach with JOIN but I cannot find the right syntax.

Comment: If _the datasets in table P that do not have a corresponding entry in table A_ ... yes, then no records will be returned. Would did you expect?

Comment: I would like to have "FROM P LEFT OUTER JOIN A ON A.[NUMBER] = VAL(P.[PLUX])) so that also these datasets are returned but with the join on the R table as well

Comment: I would create a query that returns all fields of P plus `VAL(P.[PLUX])) As NumPlux`, then use the query GUI designer to build the query using A(rtikel), R, and the first query as sources.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gustav
The GUI designer helped (didn't even know it is there - just used SQL so far).

```
SELECT P.ColumnX, A.ColumnY, R.ColumnZ
FROM (P LEFT OUTER JOIN A.[NUMBER]) = VAL(P.[PLUX]))
INNER JOIN R ON P.[PRGUID] = R.[RGUID]
WHERE R.[TIMEST] > #yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss# 
AND  R.[TIMEST] < #yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss#
```